# Alertify / Display message on page load 1 time instead of button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, alertify

Here's my current setup. I would like to display the message on a homepage once instead of href link. The latest updates. No luck with the listener I believe:

```
<script>
function reset() {
    $("#toggleCSS").attr("href", "../themes/alertify.default.css");
    alertify.set({
        labels: {
            ok: "OK",
        },
        delay: 5000,
        buttonFocus: "ok"
    });
}

// ==============================
// Standard Dialogs


var listener = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#el').off(listener);


    $(document).ready(function() {
        reset();
        alertify.alert("Message en français ici / Message en anglais ici");
        return false;
    });

};
$('#el').on('click', listener);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to execute the `click`-triggered behavior only once, and then let `#alert` behave normally use the [`$.one('click', ...)`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method.

Also make sure you prevent the default behavior by using [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

This will automatically remove the listener after the first usage.

The following two are equivalent

```
var listener = function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#el').off(listener);
    /* your logic */
};
$('#el').on('click', listener);
```

and

```
var listener = function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    /* your logic */
};
$('#el').one('click', listener);
```

## Edit

If you wish to have the logic executed on page load, then use the [`$(document).ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) listener

Comment: Thanks Matyas, but how can I get the alert on page load (instead of href)?

Comment: You should use then: `$(document).ready(function () { ... });`

Comment: Got a hard time figuring out the syntax for this live above. Btw, your one time event works like a charm!!!

Comment: Matyas, I've updated the code above. Could you give it a try? The listener doesn't work anymore I think. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot "try it" out, since I don't have your environment. Perhaps you could prepare a [fiddle](jsfiddle.net) and tell exactly the sequence of actions you are expecting to have. Like: Page loads > alert pops up > click on link >etc.. or Page loads > click on link > alert pops up > etc... Because it is not quite clear what you wish to achieve. But your modified code will not work, because you only listen to `document.ready` after you click on tha `a`. Which most possibly will not be triggered (the listener for `document.ready`)

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code

```
  $("#alert").on( 'click', function () {
    reset();
    alertify.alert("Message en français ici / Message en anglais ici");
    return false;
});
```

by below code.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    reset();
    alertify.alert("Message en français ici / Message en anglais ici");
    return false;
});
```

So that this will show alert on page load

Comment: Thanks Swapnil. I was over complicating things... Would you know why the listener is not working anymore?

Comment: I made code updates above. The listener does not work anymore. Can you please take a look Swapnil?

Comment: Need to debug and check for javascript errors in browser. Not sure. Yes i can help you.